# Anyone has the logic for the following puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle

I have an n*n matrix. 
Each vertex has a degree associated with it. Degree is the number of lines that can be drawn to its neighbouring vertices. 
I am generating an array containing degrees of each vertex.
For example, array {1,2,2,1} implements the following two solutions.

[image]

solution 1

[image: solution 2]

solution 2

what i want is, when i get the array i want to know whether it has one solution or more than one solution.

This is another example {0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3} has more than one solutions.

Comment: Better post at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I read about this somewhere. I think there are two approaches to it: Either brute-force or refined.

**Brute-force:** Try any combination of lines that is allowed by the degree of each vertex recursively and back-track if a contradiction is found (a node gets in-line-count that does not correspond to its out-degree).

**Refined:** Instead of starting with the first node, start with the nodes that have the most links. This also recurses through the remaining nodes but the remaining nodes are updated by what **remains** of their degree (e.g. if a previous node already has a line to it then the node's degree is decremented). The reason why this is faster is, that nodes with a large degree pose a higher restriction on their surrounding nodes, e.g. if a node reduces a neighbor-node's remaining degree to 0 then there are 0 cases that have to be considered for that node.